# Javascript Module Type

Tags: javascript, module

I have a file index.blade.php

```
...
<script type="module" src="{{mix('assets/js/igd/dokter/index.js')}}"></script>
```

/dokter/index.js

```
import {
  getKunjungan,
  ...
} from "./actions/kunjungan.js";
import * as diagnosa from "./accessibility/diagnosa.js";
(() => {
  $("#btn-search").click((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let search_val = $("#chat-search").val();
    let tgl = $("#date-breadcrumb").val();
    return getKunjungan(search_val, tgl);
    // return window.location = `?nama_pasien=${search_val}`
  });
});
```

/kunjungan.js

```
export const getKunjungan = (
  {
    nama_pasien = null,
    tgl = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
    ttv = 1,
    id_layanan = 0,
  },
  succ
) => {
    ...
    return succ([total_menunggu, total_sudah, total_pasien_lain]);
  }).fail((a) => {
    return errorHandler(null, a);
  });
};
```

diagnosa.js

```
import { BASE_PATH } from "../variables.js";
$(".btn-cara-pulang").click((e) => {
...
});
export const deleteDiagnosa = (diagnosa_id) => {
  const url = `${BASE_URL}${BASE_PATH}/diagnosa/` + diagnosa_id;
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "DELETE",
    headers: {
      "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"),
    },
    // data: {
    //   req_diagnosa_id: diagnosa_id,
    // },
    success: function (data) {
      $(`.del-diagnosa-${diagnosa_id}`).closest("tr").remove();
      return successHandler("Berhasil Hapus");
    },
    error: function (data) {
      return errorHandler(null, data);
    },
  });
};
```

i am new for this module type pattern, i'm confused

1. index.js is the main app
2. at diagnosa.js there is onclick event that should run ($(".btn-cara-pulang").click)
3. that onclick event is not triggerring when im not using import * as diagnosa at index.js

Is my pattern / what i'm doing here is true / false, or is there anything should i know like best practice to use module type pattern

Thank you in advance

i have tried to delete the import * as diagnosa statement but event is not clicking

Comment: The click event handler is assigned inside an arrow function which **you never call** (or even assign anywhere)

Comment: Also `$` seems to be undefined

Comment: did you check browser console ? it might have some error logs.

Comment: i import jquery before with script tag @Quentin

Comment: Nope no error on log, my program work but i feel unconfortable with the pattern @bogdanoff

Comment: as quentin pointed out you never called that function in `/dokter/index.js`.  change last line from `});` to `})();`

Comment: So i can conclude that there is nothing wrong with my pattern style? Just a wrong syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
(() => {
  $("#btn-search").click((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let search_val = $("#chat-search").val();
    let tgl = $("#date-breadcrumb").val();
    return getKunjungan(search_val, tgl);
    // return window.location = `?nama_pasien=${search_val}`
  });
});
```

you define a `function` but you do not reference or call it, so the `click` handler will never be triggered. You will need to change it to

```
(() => {
  $("#btn-search").click((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let search_val = $("#chat-search").val();
    let tgl = $("#date-breadcrumb").val();
    return getKunjungan(search_val, tgl);
    // return window.location = `?nama_pasien=${search_val}`
  });
})();
```

It's wise to differentiate between bugs and styling. The above is a bug, but it's independent from styling. It's just the case that there is no point in defining a `function` that's not referenced nor called. Yet, if you feel uncomfortable with the syntax you use, then you are well-advised to ponder about what exactly makes you uncomfortable. It's possible that you are just not used to it and later on you will be comfortable with it. Or there is an objective problem with your code and you need to reorganize it. Sort out your thoughts, formulate your feelings into factual statements and then you will know whether there is indeed a problem and you will also know what the problem is if there is one.